# Added Android TV to existing app, now can only support back to Android SDK 17

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-tv

I added Android TV support to an existing app. I then had to increase the min SDK version to 17 from 14. Indication was the leanback library could not support below SDK 21, however, I seem to be able to use 17 as the minimum. I did have to add the following to my Android Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v14.preference" />
```

This has to be a configuration issue in the manifest. Is there any further configuration required? The app does work on phones, tablets, and Nexus Player. It just doesn't support back to Android SDK 14, which has been requested by some users.

Code is here:
https://github.com/MythTV-Clients/MythtvPlayerForAndroid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Leanback library has a minimum SDK version of 17. If you want to add Android TV support, you will need to add another module.

Looking at your project, it seems like "domain" and "presentation" are separate modules for the project. You can add one for "TV" and put TV specific code there. When the user installs the APK the correct version will be downloaded.

You can put phone specific code in a "phone" module. Shared code can be a "shared" module which can be compiled for both platforms.

Let me know if you have any questions with using modules.

Comment: OK, that is what I was thinking needed to happen. I take it the phone and TV version each has their own manifest.  I see needing 3 subprojects. 1 for phone, 1 for TV, one for common MVP stuff. Then my existing domain will still be the api for interacting with the backend through the implementation in the data subproject.

Comment: This worked. I have a branch with the app broken out from the tv into separate modules.  My presentation subproject is now an Android Library. It is primarily responsible for the MVP code common across both types of clients. https://github.com/MythTV-Clients/MythtvPlayerForAndroid/tree/feature/issue_115_lower_api_restriction

Comment: hi, I have this same problem, what I didn't understand is that when I make another module for tv, should I repeat all the same java files like api repo and some architectures things that won't use in tv view again in tv module?or I can have interactions between my mobile module and tv module?

Comment: You can create a shared library module which hosts code used by every other module. Then you have TV/mobile app modules which use the shared code and custom code.